# hold reference object inside std::optional

Tags: c++, stdoptional

I am having issue when trying to pass a reference object inside std::optional as a function argument.Does it not support storing reference objects ?
Example -

```
void fun(std::optional<ClassA& obj>)
```

What exatly does this error mean -
`static_assert failed due to requirement '!is_reference`

`static_assert(!is_reference_v<_Tp>)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cpp [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) states quite clearly:

> There are no optional references; a program is ill-formed if it
> instantiates an optional with a reference type. Alternatively, an
> optional of a std::reference_wrapper of type T may be used to hold a
> reference.

So use `std:reference_wrapper` as suggested.

Footnote: there are movement in the cpp commitee to enable references in `std::optional`. We might get them in future.

Comment: The other side of the argument is that there already *is* an optional reference: a pointer

Comment: @Caleth: True, so `std::optional<T&>` is trivial to implement. It's about semantics, really: a `T*` is historically burdened with unclear ownership. A `std::optional<T&>` definitely does not own the object it references, and passing it to `delete` will give an error.